# Unable to pull docker image - Repository not found

Tags: docker, firewall, rhel

I'm unable to pull docker images in my environment. I think it's blocked by company firewall, but I'm not sure why It gets layer info and later It prints that repository is not found.

```
sudo docker pull hello-world
latest: Pulling from hello-world
50a54e1f9180: Pulling fs layer
7a5a2d73abce: Pulling fs layer
Pulling repository hello-world
Repository not found
```

Docker version: (I cannot upgrade to newest docker on RHEL 6.9)

```
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d/1.7.1
```

Could somebody explain me which protocols (https only?) are used during docker image pulling phase and what addresses are contacted ("https://registry-1.docker.io/v2" only?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that firewall was blocking connections during pulling images.
Docker registry uses CDN so more URLs need to be allowed and not only registry URL.

I requested to allow the following URLs on company firewall and it is working now.

```
dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net
auth.docker.io
elb-registry.us-east-1.aws.dckr.io.
us-east-1-elbregis-10fucsvj1tcgy-133821800.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
registry-1.docker.io
registry-origin.docker.io
index.docker.io
elb-io.us-east-1.aws.dckr.io
us-east-1-elbio-rm5bon1qaeo4-623296237.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Docker log file (/var/log/docker) help me to identify root problem.
There were the following errors:

```
level=error msg="Error from V2 registry: Get https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/78/78445dd45222097f5f8d5a16e48dc19c4ca162dcdb80010ab6f1ccfc7e2c0fa3/data?Expires=1493033299&Signature=DiEmffSxF1F9z-SRoGyX3NwzfeQY3BhE2Du3aPb1qy9VglXyn1mus7Xy9Y~DQnwaQ9IIN71FboK5lOAiN1Qj-x662qhioi72CJ-v02fiMHqC03FDb0l4LyULquU8GaalW3uZG4hdfuSqOBQ1qo9HEcxhMyQGqOqpfPUKjUlHqm8_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q: read tcp 52.85.173.110:443: connection reset by peer"
```

The list of URLs which needs to be allowed I found here:
https://forums.docker.com/t/list-of-docker-hub-mirror-sites-to-configure-proxy-whitelist/20845/2

Answer (score 1):

Docker images can consist of multiple layers. By default, the Docker daemon will pull three layers of an image at a time but will pull less in case an image has lesser layers. Also, if no tag is provided, Docker Engine uses the `:latest` tag as a default. Above is a basic log of your pull request indicating docker trying to pull layers of the image but failing, may be due to firewall restrictions or older docker version.

> Docker uses the `https://` protocol to communicate with a registry,
>   unless the registry is allowed to be accessed over an insecure
>   connection.

Not sure what all addresses it tries to connect to pull an image.

Comment: If firewall blocks communication then docker should not get information about layers ... or am I wrong ?

Comment: Each Docker image references a list of read-only layers that represent filesystem differences. Layers are stacked on top of each other to form a base for a container’s root filesystem. What {fs} here means is {filesystem}

Comment: @martinsefcik In that case also it will show `Pulling fs layer`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, It helped me a bit to understand how the layers work.

Comment: @martinsefcik Glad it helped :)